# Loading a (Dynamic?) DLL at runtime in a ASP.NET WebSite

Tags: asp.net, dll, web

I am using some DB like product called 'Sesame'. They provide c# pinvoke files and a DLL... I am used to just doing the old 'Add Reference' and move on.. But for whatever reason this DLL cannot work that way.. The PINVOKE file refers to it (I guess in the working directory)..

So then I move this working demo it a ASP.NET 'Web Site'.. BNow I am confused.. I put the PINVOKE file and the dll in the App_Code/CSCode... But the source code cannot find this DLL..

Where shoudl this DLL reside ??? In the ASP.NET temp files?? Since that is where it compiles everything?? But that doesnt seem right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any DLL needs to reside in the /bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

IT seems you are right.. Though there seems to be a work around where the DLLs can be pulled in from here..

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setdlldirectory

Also I need to run theis dll in 32-bit mode on the app pool in IIS 7.0.. I hope there is no down side to this ?